# Numeric conversion errors with IIS 8

Tags: vb.net, string, double, iis-8

We recently came across an error with converting strings to doubles which would only occur on one of our servers (and not on the rest.)

```
e.g.: Conversion from string "1.5" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

We tried changing the regional settings and as well as the Decimal symbol under the Additional settings in the region settings.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error we located the .NET Globalization settings in IIS. (You can find it in the Features pane when clicking on the Server in the Connections pane.)

We changed the Culture and the UI Culture to English (en) and the error went away.